# How to schedule a python/R script to run on a powerBI dataset

Tags: python, r, powerbi

I already have a R script that will dump the data from a given dataset in powerBI to .csv file in local desktop. But I want to schedule this script to run every day.
How can this be achieved?
Can this be achieved without using gateway tool available in internet blogs like https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Schedule-Automated-Data-Exports-from-Power-BI-using-a-simple-R/ba-p/1606313

Comment: I don't want to refresh the reports. But I want the R/Python script to run in my local machine daily

Comment: On a Windows machine, you can use Task Scheduler.
On Linux, you can use cron job.
Or you could build a Docker image with a cron job.

Comment: `system.sleep()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some sort of Task Scheduler depending on the OS you're using, or you can download On-Premise Gateway Personal Mode ([Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55768)) and run it through that on Power BI Service.
This gateway will be available only when using your account and this is great if your R script is embedded inside Power Query, then with each refresh of the dataset, the script will be run as well and you will get your .csv updated.